# How to invoke completion block in CloudKit in Swift 2 in iOS 9?

Tags: ios, swift, cloudkit

I did not managed to translate my working iOS8 code snippet into iOS 9 Swift 2 Xcode version 7.0 beta (7A120f).

My last attempt was:

```
saveRecordsOperation.perRecordCompletionBlock {
    (record:CKRecord, recordID:CKRecordID, error:NSError) -> Void in

    print("perRecordCompletionBlock \(record)")
}
```

But Xcode says:

```
AppDelegate.swift:929:34: Cannot invoke 'perRecordCompletionBlock' with an argument list of type '((CKRecord, CKRecordID, NSError) -> Void)'
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, here is the solution:

```
       saveRecordsOperation.perRecordCompletionBlock = {
            (record:CKRecord?, error:NSError?) -> Void in

            print("perRecordCompletionBlock \(record)")
        }
```

There where two issues actually: one I introduced while dealing around to find a solution when I desperately added recordID, while the second was we now must use equal sign to pass the code block.

Hope it helps.

Comment: @EricD. Well, it's weird. If I introduce the CKRecordID? argument, as suggested by the doc, I got the error again:  Tuple types '(CKRecord?, NSError?)' and '(CKRecord?, CKRecordID?, NSError?)' have a different number of elements (2 vs. 3)

Comment: It does not compile If I conform to the doc as I stated in the comment. My current (weird) solution works. I am also worried @EricD. Btw, are you working with Swift2/iOS9 and CloudKit as well? Any working code on this on your side to compare with?